# How to create 2 separate windows in WPF with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I want to create 2 separate windows in xaml and I want to control them separately from the code part. Do you have any idea how to do that ? If you can provide some code examples, I will be appreciated.

Thank you from now...

Comment: Why not simply make two windows? Must they be in the same XAML file? If so, why?

Comment: I tried the google search. But it gave me the result like this: One big main window,and one small window inside of this window. What I want to try is to control them seperately at different locations. Not inside of the one window...

@Martin: They dont have to be in the same XAML file, but they have to be controlled from one code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a second `Window` (the first one being MainWindow.xaml) in your project (right click your project-> Add -> Window). Let's call it BobbyWindow.

In the constructor of MainWindow.xaml.cs, call:

```
BobbyWindow bWin = new BobbyWindow();
bwin.Owner = this;
bWin.Show();
```

voila.

**EDIT:** additional info to reflect the comments

The main difference between this:

```
public MainWindow() 
{ 
   InitializeComponent(); 
   Window1 bWin = new Window1(); 
   bWin.Owner = this; 
   bWin.Show(); 
}
```

And that:

```
Window1 bWin = new Window1(); 

public MainWindow() 
    { 
       InitializeComponent(); 

       bWin.Owner = this; 
       bWin.Show(); 
    }
```

Is that in the **first case**, bWin is **local to the MainWindow()** constructor, which means it only exists within the brackets of MainWindow().
In the **second case**, bWin is **local to the class**, which means it is only accessible from within the boundaries of the MainWindow **class**

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I use " this" for another window. I tried to give another name to call, but it didnt work. I'm not proffessional in this topic. If you explain me what to write, I will be appreciated. 

Thanks...

Comment: "this" refers to the current object. Depending on where you write "this" it points to a different object.

Comment: I have one main window and your window. I make lots of things with main window by using "this" . So, I have to use something else to reach your window. I mean I cant do this:  BobbyWindow.Visibility =....  It doesnt accept this. I use this.Visibility for main window. How can I call your window to reach it?

Comment: Oh, i see, put the first line outside the method, then you can do dbWin.Visibility = ... anywhere in your main window.

Comment: Maybe I put this small code somewhere wrong. Where I put these 3 code lines is here:  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Window1 bWin = new Window1();
            bWin.Owner = this; 
            bWin.Show();
        }

So, If I write like this, I cant reach to bWin from anywhere. Let me try to put first line out of the method.

Comment: Yes, I put the first line out of method and I can reach it..It worked :) Thank you for your help.